# Can't access Java Applet bound in Cordova iOS app

Tags: java, javascript, ios, cordova, applet

I'm having a problem accessing my Java Applet from my app. The app itself is a Cordova iOS app and therefor written in JavaScript/HTML/CSS.
I read some tutorials about how to implement an Applet so I started my first steps by copy&paste one of the "examples" I found.

So I added to my index.html:

```html
<body><applet id="socketApplet" width="0" height="0" archive="applet/socketApplet.jar" name="socketApplet" code="socketApplet" scriptable="true"></body>
```

and in my JavaScript I'm trying to access it via:

```
document.socketApplet.testApplet();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("socketApplet").testApplet();
```

but none of them works.

//edit: Worth noting that the Applet itself runs fine in Eclipse.

I debugged it with Safari Developer Web Information which states:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementById("socketApplet").testApplet()')
```

For me that means it can't find the applet file, so I moved it around a bit (e.g. in the index.html directory) to make sure it's not just a real "find it" problem but it didn't help.

For informational purposes:

- Using a MacBook Pro with version 10.9.3
- An iPad4 with iOS 6.1.3 (Testing reasons)
- Writing the Applet with Eclipse Keplar (pasted it in there though)
- Compiled it as a runnable jar file.
- Xcode 5.1.1

The App itself runs fine, it's only the applet which I can't get to work.

Applet code:

```
import java.applet.*;

public class socketApplet extends Applet {

public void init() {
    System.out.println("Applet initialisiert.");
}

public void start() {
    System.out.println("Applet gestartet.");
}

public void paint() {
    System.out.println("Applet aktualisiert.");
}

public void stop() {
    System.out.println("Applet angehalten.");
}

public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("Applet beendet.");
}

public String testApplet() {
    System.out.println("Applet getestet.");
    return "Yep, I'm the Applet.";
}

}
```

Edit2: When checking `document.applets.length` I get the value "1" so something is there.
And when referring to the applet like `document.applets[0].code` I still get a response ("socketApplet" in this case). Trying `document.applets[0].testApplet()` however still does nothing. Function returns a String which I print out so if it works there should be something.

Comment: *"`width="0" height="0"`"*  It would not surprise me in the least if a 0x0 applet was not launched at all.  Increase the size and see if there are any messages in place of (where you expect to see) the applet.

Comment: Increased size to 1/1 just so that it has some sort of size but it didn't fix it. When setting the size to lets say 1000/1000 I see in the Safari Web Inspector that the applet takes up nearly the full screen but isn't visible. Normally the applet shouldn't be visible in the app since my plan is to use it for Webservice handling. I know this can be done via JavaScript but that isn't allowed due to security issues...